# TFS Rest API: Extension Data Service unreliable?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, azure-devops-rest-api

My TFS hub extension (on-premise 2015.3) does not load correctly because of unexpected extension data service behaviour and not getting its needed preferences. The extension users store - after installation once during first-start/loading the hub page - extension preferences on the collection-level, as key-value pairs (getValue/setValue from extension data service API), and if the hub page gets reloaded the preferences are stored already. It's like an Application Wizard/First start Dialog in my hub page.

But when I install the extension on another collection of the same TFS and want to store (=setValue) preferences for that collection it comes back with OK (can see it in F12->network capture of Internet Explorer), but cannot find these previously entered/stored key-value pairs when refreshing (=getValue on the key) my hub. It delivers an empty value for the key, and the "first-start" dialog reappears again, what shouldnt happen if there was a value for the key. Already debugged, it always comes back empty (empty value) in that collection. No error from the service, nothing to capture, nothing to debug.

**Can I check somewhere else (on the TFS logs, event viewer, or database) for deeper debugging?**

I also tried with Powershell and restcalls manually by putting and getting the json on the Rest urls for the extension data service. In one collection it works (manually and per hub extension) but for the other collection the data service does not work.

Is there a known issue in 2015.3 in the extension data service? I really have a problem if I cannot store the preferences of the extension anywhere - storing it to an default source control path would be an alternative, but I do not want to force the projects to check-in preferences for my extension...

EDIT:
Adding relevant code snippet

```
function showSourceControlDialog(project: string/*TFS_Core_Contracts.TeamProjectReference*/) {
    return Q.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        //setTimeout(function () {
        var thatProjectIDclean = project/*.id*/.replace(/-/g, "_");
        var enterSourceControlPathDialog = VSS_Controls_Dialogs.show(VSS_Controls_Dialogs.ModalDialog, {
            title: "Please now enter source control path for " + thisProjectName /*project.name*/,
            content: $("<p/>").addClass("confirmation-text").html("<label><b>Source Control Path</b> to preferences file, e.g. '$/" + thisProjectName /*thisCollectionName + "/" + project.name*/ + "/.../...xml:</label><input id='enterSourceControlPathInput' size='40'/>" /*+ projectName + ".xml"*/),
            useBowtieStyle: true,
            buttons: {
                "Cancel": function () {
                    enterSourceControlPathDialog.close();
                    enterSourceControlPathDialog.dispose();
                    reject("cancelled");
                },
                "OK": function () {
                    sourceControlPath = $("input#enterSourceControlPathInput").val();
                    if (sourceControlPath) {
                        setConfiguration(thatProjectIDclean, sourceControlPath).then(function (setToThisPath) {
                            console.log(setToThisPath);
                            enterSourceControlPathDialog.close();
                            enterSourceControlPathDialog.dispose();
                            $(".bss-button").show();
                            $(".bss-tvc").show();
                            resolve(sourceControlPath);
                        }).catch(function (error) {
                            reject(error);
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        //}, 10000);
    });
}

function setConfiguration(key: string, value: string) {
    return Q.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // Get data service
        VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.ExtensionData).then(function (dataService: IExtensionDataService) {
            // Set value in collection scope
            dataService.setValue(pssVersion + "_" + key, value/*, { scopeType: "Project Collection" }*/).then(function (setToThis: string) {
                console.log(pssVersion + "_" + key + " is now " + setToThis );
                resolve(setToThis);
            }, function (error) {
                reject(error);
                console.log(error);
        }, function (error) {
            reject(error);
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
}

function getConfiguration(key: string) {
    return Q.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // Get data service
        VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.ExtensionData).then(function (dataService: IExtensionDataService) {
            // Get value in collection scope
            dataService.getValue(pssVersion + "_" + key/*, { scopeType: "Project Collection" }*/).then(function (gotThis: string) {
                sourceControlPath = gotThis;
                console.log(pssVersion + "_" + key + " is " + gotThis );
                resolve(gotThis);
            }, function (error) {
                reject(error);
                console.log(error);
            });
        }, function (error) {
            reject(error);
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
}

try {
    console.log(thisProjectIDclean);
    getConfiguration(thisProjectIDclean).then(function (resultPath: string) {
      console.log(resultPath);
    console.log(sourceControlPath);
    if (!resultPath) {
            //getProjects().then(function (resultProjects: TFS_Core_Contracts.TeamProjectReference[]) {
            //    resultProjects.forEach(function (resultProject: TFS_Core_Contracts.TeamProjectReference) {
                    showSourceControlDialog(thisProjectID/*resultProject*/).then(function () {
                        getXMLTree();
                    }, function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            //    }, function (error) {
            //        console.log(error);
            //    });
            //}, function (error) {
            //    console.log(error);
            //});
        } else {
            getXMLTree();
        }
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: You need to provide some code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: What's the detail code? Can you share it on the OneDrive? On the other hand, I don't think you can check something else for deeper debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately what you are trying to do is not possible. Referring to the [example](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/data-storage) the "maximum" scope you can store extension data in is the "Project Collection".
From my experience while fiddling with ExtensionDataService it is not possible to query data from a "foreign" collection.